# In Tad Williams' novels of the Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn trilogy, what is the nature of the secret Padreic learned that made him so despondent?

Tags: tad-williams, memory-sorrow-thorn

We discover later in the novels that Padreic is Osten Ard's most learned magician/wizard (outside of the Sithi themselves), quite possibly the most in many centuries. He is able to cause substantial things to happen... he conjures a staircase out of nothing allowing the heroes to escape as a castle that is crumbling around them, just as an example.

But the books hint that years before during his studies he learned some secret that provoked him to become a depressed drunk. What is the nature of this secret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padreic had read a copy of Nisses' Du Svardenvyrd "The Weird of the Great Swords". This brought him great despair, leading him to abandon the League of Scrollbearers and become a drunkard.

In Padreic's own words:

"But copy or no, it contained the words of Nisses...No one could read the dreadful things I did, then look at the world around him, and disbelieve."

"But by the time I had finished reading it, I was no longer a Scrollbearer. I knew it in my heart. From the moment I turned the last page I gave up the love of learning for the love of oblivion - the two cannot live together. Even before I found Nisses' book, I had gone far down the wrong paths, learning things than no man should learn who wishes to sleep well at night."

"They (other Scrollbearers) were so certain that if they could look closely enough at the nature of the world they could divine all its purposes...but I had something they did not, a book the mere reading of which would would not only prove to them the things I already suggested, but would crumble the pillars of their understanding.  I was full of rage...but I was also full of despair."

"The world is different once Nisses has explained it. It is as though the pages of his book were dipped in some slow poison that kills the spirit. I touched them all."

" 'It sounds horrible.' Miriamele remembered the image she had seen...a horned giant with red eyes...Could it be better not to know some things? 'Horrible indeed (said Padreic), but only because it reflected the true terror that lurked beneath the waking world, the shadows which are the obverse image of sunlight.'"

Reading Du Svardenvyrd disillusioned, frightened, and pushed Padreic to great despair. In response, he ceased being a scholar and sought oblivion in strong drink.  It is not clear that the he discovered one particularly devastating secret within its pages.

Interestingly, the Author's Warning in The Dragonbone Chair (book 1), which is even before the Foreword, has this: "He who is certain he knows the ending of things when he is only beginning them is either extremely wise or extremely foolish; no matter which is true, he is certainly an *unhappy* man, for he has put a knife in the heart of wonder."  Padreic is profoundly unhappy. Du Svardenvyrd is, among other things, a book of prophecy. It seems possible (maybe likely) Padreic concluded he knew "the ending of things" after reading Nisses' book and this is what brought his great despair.

Comment: The "ending of things" is that the good guys win, though at a cost. I don't think that would make anyone particularly unhappy, at least by itself. There must be more to it, don't you think?

Comment: In Nisses book, the "ending of things" is not happy."The end of the world," (Padreic) repeated. He took a deep breath. "Lady, if you and I and this troll could somehow slaughter every Norn in the Hayholt-every Norn in Stormspike, too-still it would make no difference. It is too late to do anything. It was always too late. The world, the green fields of Osten Ard, the people of its lands... they are doomed. And I have known it since before I met you." He looked up imploringly. "Of course I am bitter, Miriamele. Of course I am almost mad. Because I know beyond doubt that there is no hope."

Comment: That's pretty close to the answer I'm looking for. So what is it that Padreic knows? Is it related to how the Rimmersmen and Sithi came to the world from across the water? Is this an Otherworld simulation that's soon to be turned off?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Otherland, but I'm betting Osten Ard isn't a VR sim. My guess is that Padreic's hopelessness stems from a mistaken belief that Nisses has foretold the destruction of mankind by the vengeful Sithi. Plus he has lost any faith in goodness, especially in himself: "...for I had dwelt in the depths so long that I saw nothing left that was good but nothingness itself."

Comment: Maybe you should read it. The VR sim is composed of thousands of separate worlds, all connected by rivers or waterways. To travel from world to world, one crosses the water. He made it so explicit in both, I've never been able to decide if I'm just reading too much into it or not.

Comment: I agree with Skarl when he quotes "Because I know beyond doubt that there is no hope". That's the key idea here. Oh, there is always hope, and the story proves it, but in Cadrach's mind he has discovered something so menacing, so pervasive, and so strong that he is certain that there really IS no hope. His knowledge probably also serves as an excuse for his personal weaknesses; If he didn't suffer from depression and alcoholism, and if he'd never been tortured by Pryrates, he might not have been so willing to lay down and die.